# Null Reference exception DNN Core 5.6.3

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

My site has been running fine for sometime now until recently I see in the event viewer a null reference exception in the DNN core:

> ```
> DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.GetStatus() in
> ```
>
> F:\Builds\Maintenance\WorkingDirectory\Library\Common\Globals.vb:line
>   1125    at DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.InitializeApp(HttpApplication
>   app) in
>   F:\Builds\Maintenance\WorkingDirectory\Library\Common\Initialize.vb:line
>   138    at DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.Init(HttpApplication app) in
>   F:\Builds\Maintenance\WorkingDirectory\Library\Common\Initialize.vb:line
>   228    at DotNetNuke.Common.Global.Global_BeginRequest(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

the line 1125 is:

```
_Status = UpgradeStatus.None
```

Which is a property of the Globals class and an Enum

Also when this happens it doesnt just do it once then sort its self it does it roughly every minute for an hour or so.

I made sure all `dataprovider.instances` are either in a using or a try catch finally or self closing(if the reader is not used)

Any suggestion most welcome, as I'm officially lost.

Thanks

Comment: tried turning off Auto Upgrade in Host Settings?

Comment: @karbonphyber do you mean the autoupgrade setting in the web.config? or the check for updates in host settings?  Web.config one is set to off and the check for updates is checked.

Comment: I think there is something missing from the error message.  That line cannot throw a null reference exception as it is assigning a constant to a value type.  Can you edit in the whole exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @ScottS that is the full stack trace and error message. I think what im seeing is more than likely the effect of something else but I cant get a trace back to the point of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had a look at the release.config and it have autoupdate=true set that to false and it hasnt been an issue since.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what ScottS mentioned, that line is setting a static enum value, so I don't see how a NullReferenceException could be thrown. Indeed, it could be a side-effect from something else.

That particular error is coming from Global.asax BeginRequest, which calls `Initialize.Init(app)`. The only thing I can think of is to check your Http Modules. Both the RequestfilterModule and the UrlRewriteModule (which are default DNN http modules) also call `Initialize.Init(app)`.

Perhaps check your web.config and IIS (particularly if you're running IIS 7) and make sure everything checks out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have checked the web.config, and IIS (running 6) both seem fine. However I did look at release.config and that had autoupdate=true (I know this should in no way sort the issue) so I changed it to false and it hasnt done it since. I'd Still Like to know the reason why but the effects have gone now